# Getting error in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting this error when I start Ubuntu terminal in my PC

[Screenshot of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSJWy.jpg)

```
wsl: Unknown key 'wsl2.default' in C:\Users\Rimzhim\.wslconfig:2
<3>WSL (360) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2801: Failed to translate D:\App files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
<3>WSL (360) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2801: Failed to translate D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Version: WSL2
Distro Version: 20.04

People are saying that It is with environment variables, I am unable to solve it. I am new to this and I have very little knowledge, so please guide me.

Thank you in advance!

I tried to check environment variables, but could not find anything relevant

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

you error message suggest you have tried to write this, and hence got `wsl.default` key error:

```
[wsl2]
default=...
```

There is no such option usable in `.wslconfig` file. check this link for all options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-setting-for-wslconfig

---

in case you wanted to set a "default user" here, then this is a misunderstanding: you cannot set this on this global setting file, and the key should be "user.default" instead. check local options on that same linked page (`wsl.conf` file).